# How to get the Github repository in Drone.io

Tags: github, drone.io

I have setup the drone host in my development environment. And I use github account as the authentication to login my drone website. After login, drone shows I have empty repository list. However, I didn't create any repository on github but I have an admin permission on one of the private repository. How can I let drone dicover that repository? Is there any configuration to be done for that case?

Comment: On the "Account" page, doesn't the repository show up?

Comment: It doesn't show up. This repository is not owned by my account. But I have the admin permission for this repository.

Comment: This might be a bug, I've seen a similar issue for Bitbucket: https://github.com/drone/drone/issues/1667

Comment: Yes that issue is for Bitbucket but not sure it is an issue for Github. Where can I get confirmed about this issue?

Comment: I'd recommend checking the third party application policy for your account, and for the organization that owns the repository. It is very possible the organization has restrictions on third party applications accessing its repositories. For more details see https://github.com/blog/1941-organization-approved-applications

Comment: I already add drone in the authorized application and gave the 'Full control of private repositories' permission.

Comment: have you confirmed the organization that owns the repository has enabled the drone application at the organization-level? This is a common issue and would explain what you are seeing.

Comment: note that if you feel you feel you have enabled everything at both the user account and organization level, perhaps you could include screenshots of the two screens to confirm? What does the `/api/user/repos/remote` endpoint return in drone? Do you see your repository there? If not, it is not being returned from GitHub so perhaps you need to consult GitHub support.

Comment: Which version of drone? 0.4.x or 0.5.x?

Comment: I am using drone 0.5